# Set size Radio Button android

Tags: android, radio-button, background-color

I need to change the size of the circle of the radio button and also the color when I clicked it. It should be like the image below. 
Do you have some idea or some example? Thanks

[image]

Comment: What code have you tried? What isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use a custom drawable background for your radio button as an example -

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_drawable_toggle_background"
    android:button="@null"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="RadioButton" />
```

and in your drawable create your `custom_drawable_toggle_background.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_drawable_background_selected" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_drawable_background_unselected"    android:state_checked="false"/>

 </selector>
```